# Redirecting *.domain.com to www.domain.com with HTTP or HTTPS prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The code below is a redirecting script that redirects visitors of my website to www.domain.com if they are not on it (like for example if they are on domain.com or somesub.domain.com). I modified it, to redirect them to either HTTPS or HTTP, depending on the link that they typed or got (hot)linked to.

It is working, but i'm guessing there could be an easier way to do this or that there is some room for improvement. Can someone double check / comment on this? Many thanks in advance.

```
# redirect any HTTP traffic that is not http://www.domain.com/*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect any HTTPS traffic that is not https://www.domain.com/*  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule .* http%1://www.domain.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please explain the new line 3 and modified line 4? I would like to learn what it does..

Comment: `%{HTTPS}` contains `on` in case of https. So by adding the `s` in case of https it will match `on(s)` and `%1` will contain `s` and %1 will be empty if not. So in line 4 you either have http, or http*s*.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you very much for this better script and usefull information!

Comment: I know this is old but can you explain what the `|` pipe character does in this regex?

Comment: @billynoah without the `|` (or) the RewriteCond will not match when using regular http, so the RewriteRule will not be applied. By using the `|` (or) you say 'the string has has to start with `ons` or (`|`) not'. So the condition is always true, but the %1 will have different values depending on whether https or http is used.